# RECENTLY_PLAYED link type Spotify Apps

Tags: spotify

On the page for modes.Link in the Spotify Apps API documentation, there is a list of link types. I noticed there is a RECENTLY_PLAYED link type. Where is it used?

```
RECENTLY_PLAYED  number  14 A link to recently played.
```

I noticed by this code, in a brute force manner:

```
new models.Link("spotify:user:drsounds:recent").type
> 14
```

which means thast this is the link of type RECENTLY_PLAYED. But I get link not found error when typing this in the search box in the spotify client (windows and linux). And the play button does not recognize i at all either.

Answer (score 0):

It's an internal link, most likely used to represent the "History" tab of the play queue section of the desktop client. `spotify:user:drsounds:recent` isn't a valid URI - I imagine you get that type back because the link ends in `:recent`.

It's unusable externally, for example in the Play Button and the Apps API.

Comment: So the :recent prefix, what are this for?

Comment: The first sentence of my answer answer this.

Answer (score -1):

But I belive this is a part from a upcoming feature allowing people to see a user play history (if they opt in).

Comment: This is incorrect. Whether or not public play history is coming, this link isn't for it. Source: I'm a Spotify employee.